# Basic link placement in a Div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div with this markup:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
                <p class="bg-info">Basic Information</p>
</div>
```

which looks like:

[image: Before]

I need a link 'Add /Edit' at the right end of the div so that it looks like:

[image: After]

Tried adding a paragraph tag to the existing one with a link but it pushes the new content below.

I am new to CSS so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<p class="bg-info pull-left">Basic Information</p>
<a class="pull-right">Add/Edit</a>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jacta This is how bootstrap says to use clearfix. It's better to put clearfix on a seperate div.

Comment: Thanks Sharath, that did the job.

Comment: @SharathDaniel - As far as I can see it says: Easily clear floats by adding .clearfix to the parent element. Yes - it can be used as you do - but in that case, why add more unnecessary html to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <p class="bg-info">Basic Information <a href="#" class="pull-right">Add /Edit</a></p>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap Quick floats](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats)

I assume you're using Bootstrap because of the classes you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="container">
<div style="width:80%;float:left">
    Basic Information
</div>
<div style="width:20%;float:right">
    Add/Edit Rule
</div>    
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using bootstrap go with the other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .bg-info {display: inline; float: left;}
      .bg-info2 {display: inline; float: right; color: red;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p class="bg-info" style="float:left">Basic Information</p><p style="float:right" class="bg-info2">Basic Information</p>
    </div>
  </body>
<html>
```